# pass values from bash file to r file without echo

Tags: r, bash

I fuzz up with issue,
I create 2 files .r and .sh in same home folder, here is my code
**abc.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME="Ali"
Rscript /home/cdsw/abc.R $NAME --save
```

**abc.R**

```
#args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE), I used this option also
args <- commandArgs()
message(args)
```

I unable to get the output,
Here is the output

```
/usr/local/lib/R/bin/exec/R--sense--no-readline
```

Please help me out...

Comment: What logs your value in this case? There is no logging code in `call.sh`

Comment: Yes, there is no log code here, but this code is going to appended with some other shell script and run on a server, that maintain logs regarding "echo", so please suggest for sol

Comment: Surely it logs stdout and not `echo` specifically. If not you can use `printf`. Sounds like something that should be fixed on the logging side, but I guess you can go via temp file or something

Comment: Thank you, But can you please provide me a solution what I have to do to pass the variable from .sh script to .r file without using the keywords like echo, print, stdout etc..,

Comment: It's hard because we don't know how logging works. If it uses `set -x` style logging, it will log anything in any command so it doesn't matter which specific commands you use. If it logs stdout, then despite what you say you can use `echo` as much as you want -- as long as you write somewhere else. I would suggest trying `echo "$NAME" > /tmp/myfile` and if that doesn't show anything in the log then you can read from `/tmp/myfile` in your R program afterwards

Comment: Can you suggest me how to pass as " arguments" in .sh file & call them in r script